# Why I obtain a SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<) tryng to perform a redirection clicking a button into a SharePoint webpart?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, web-parts

I am pretty new in **SharePoint** (I am working on SharePoint 2013) and **.NET** and I have the following problem.

Into a **Web Part** I have a button and I have to insert a JavaScript redirect using the **OnClientClick** property. In my code I have done something like this:

```
ImageButton btnApplica = new ImageButton();
btnApplica.ToolTip = "Documento in Entrata";
//btnApplica.Click += btnApplica_Click_Scelta_Campi_Etichetta;
btnApplica.OnClientClick = "<script>"
                         + "function() {"
                         + "window.location.href = '" + SPContext.Current.Web.Url + "/MYPROJECTNAME WEBPART/Carica documento.aspx?mode=scelta_campi_facoltativi_etichetta&obj='" +obj 
                         + ";return false;"
                         + "}"
                         + "</script>";


//btnApplica.Click += btnApplica_Click;
//openButton.OnClientClick = "return false;";
btnApplica.ID = "btnEntrata";
btnApplica.ImageUrl = "/_layouts/15/images/myprojectname/Default/Ribbon/DocEntrataRibbon.png";
LinkButton text = new LinkButton();
text.Text = "Documento in Entrata";
text.ID = "btnEntrataTxt";
text.Width = 80;
//text.Click += btnApplica_Click;
//text.Click += btnApplica_Click_Scelta_Campi_Etichetta;
buttondiv.Controls.Add(btnApplica);
buttondiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
buttondiv.Controls.Add(text);
ribbondiv.Controls.Add(buttondiv);
```

As you can see, I am trying to create an "in client" redirection so I used the **OnClientClick** property on this button. I defined a simple JavaScript function to perform the rediration that end with the **return false** to avoid that the entire page is reloaded after the button click, this:

```
btnApplica.OnClientClick = "<script>"
                         + "function() {"
                         + "window.location.href = '" + SPContext.Current.Web.Url + "/MYPROJECTNAME WEBPART/Carica documento.aspx?mode=scelta_campi_facoltativi_etichetta&obj='" +obj 
                         + ";return false;"
                         + "}"
                         + "</script>";
```

This code section have some problem, clicking on my button it happens that:

The HTTP POST request is performed to the correct URL:

```
http://mymachine:8080/Protocollo/pg/MYPROJECTNAME WEBPART/Carica documento.aspx?mode=ant&obj=17&IsDlg=1
```

(I see it by the Network tab in Firefox, it seems to me absolutly correct)

But the page is entirely refreshed (so I don't obtain the section replacement that I expect).

Looking into the JavaScrip browser console I obtain this error message:

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
```

So I think that something went wrong defining the second statment of my simple JavaScript function (the **return false**).

I am doing:

```
+ ";return false;"
```

because I am appending the **;** symbol to say that the previous statment is complete (the **window.location.href=....** that performs the redirection) and it is follwed by the return false.

I am going crazy and I can't understand what is wrong...maybe some symbol or missed escape.

What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I would expect `OnClientClick` to translate to an `onclick` in the markup, which would expect JavaScript code, not a `<script>` tag.  The error could be indicating exactly that, the first character ('<') is not the start of JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

I think error can be when you are using `<script>` tags in OnClientClick value.
Write like this:

```
btnApplica.OnClientClick = "var ClickMySuperButton = function() {"
                         + "window.location.href = '" + SPContext.Current.Web.Url + "/MYPROJECTNAME WEBPART/Carica documento.aspx?mode=scelta_campi_facoltativi_etichetta&obj='" +obj 
                         + ";return false;"
                         + "}; ClickMySuperButton();";
```

or add your script somewhere on ascx page:

```
function ClickMySuperButton(){

};
```

and use in code-behind like this:

```
btnApplica.OnClientClick = "ClickMySuperButton();";
```